# Map java.sql.Time to Integer (milliseconds) with Dozer Mapper API

Tags: java, dozer

I have 2 classes

```
public class A
{
    public java.sql.Time startAt;
}

public class B
{
    public int startAt;
}
```

If I try to map it I get error that it cannot convert Time to Integer (milliseconds since 01.01.1970). Reading the docs I need to define customer converter. My question is

1. How to do it with Dozer API
2. Is there a way I could convert all instances of java.sql.Time to Integer? So I don't need  to define converter for each class?

Comment: A first issue with Integer is of course that it's not big enough, you really need to use Long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a custom class like this:

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.dozer.DozerConverter;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class JodaTimeToDateConverter extends DozerConverter<Date, DateTime> {


  public JodaTimeToDateConverter() {
    super(Date.class, DateTime.class);
  }


  @Override
  public DateTime convertTo(Date source, DateTime destination) {
    DateTime result = null;
    if(source != null) {
      result = new DateTime(source.getTime());
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public Date convertFrom(DateTime source, Date destination) {
    Date result = null;
    if(source != null) {
      result = new Date(source.getMillis());
    }
    return result;
  }



}
```

Then, you add a `configure` block to the dozer xml:

```
<configuration>
      <custom-converters>
            <converter type="foo.bar.CustomConverterClass">
                <class-a>java.util.Date</class-a>
                <class-b>org.joda.time.DateTime</class-b>
            </converter>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Even though I wanted to convert java.sql.Time to Integer (or Long based on comments) + use Dozer API and not dozer.xml, I will accept it.

Only problem with Dozer is that you cannot overwrite default converters (for example java.sql.Time to String)